# My leaflet map doesn't appear on my webpage

Tags: css, reactjs, leaflet, next.js

I'm using ReactJS with NextJS.

Currently my leaflet fails to fill the whole parent div on my page, in fact it doesn't appear at all. I assumed the map would fill the entire parent div, maybe someone have an idea to handle the situation.

Here my leaflet snippet:

```
const Wrapper= styled.div` 
  width:${props => props.width};
  height:${props => props.height};
`;

const location= [34.0522, -118.2457]
export default class Map extends Component{ 
  componentDidMount(){  
    // Map = require('react-leaflet').Map
    // Marker = require('react-leaflet').Marker
    // Popup = require('react-leaflet').Popup
    // TileLayer = require('react-leaflet').TileLayer
    // Tooltip = require('react-leaflet').Tooltip
    // this.setState({ showMap: true })
    this.map= L.map("map", { 

      center:location,
      zoom:12,
      zoomControl:true
    })
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 20,
      attribution: '&copy; Openstreetmap France | &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    })
    .addTo(this.map) 

    var marker = L.marker(location ,{icon: placeholder}).addTo(this.map); 
    setTimeout( ()=> {
      marker.bindPopup("Come see us, it would be awesome!", {maxWidth: "500"});  

   this.map.setView(location);
  }

  render(){ 
    return (
      <Fragment>
          <Head>
          <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.4.0/images/marker-icon-2x.png"/>
          <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.4.0/images/marker-icon.png"/>

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="yyyy"
   crossorigin=""/> 

     <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="yyyyy"
   crossorigin=""></script>   
          </Head>
        <Wrapper width="100%" height="100%" id="map"/> 
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Is there any error? If not, did you try to modify the width/height in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cant set width and height as 100% for the divs containing the map,
set width:1200px and height:600px or something of that sort. Don't worry leaflet maps are responsive

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for react specific implementation, here it is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import './styles.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    center: [51.505, -0.091],
    zoom: 13,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={this.state.center}>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And add this style to your css file.

```
.leaflet-container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the working code:https://codesandbox.io/s/2wnv7o1mlr